# How to test event handler with multiple parameters

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have a component with a click handler that takes two parameters:

```js
onClick(row, $event): void {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(row);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="onClick(row,$event)"></button>
</div>
```

How would I trigger the event with both parameters in my unit test? I would normally use `triggerEventHandler('click', {})`, but it only seems to allow providing one parameter?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to make a real click on the DOM element instead of calling the event handler yourself.

```
let buton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button')).nativeElement.click();
```

But I think your code should work, the event handler you call with `triggerEventHandler` is the method you declare in your template, not the one in the component.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was because I was stubbing the component to test it and forgot to add a `row` property to the stub.